# Is it possible to convert an integer ( short, int, long ) into a base 64 string ( and vice-versa )?

Tags: c#, base64

For example

```
long.TryParse( someString, NumberStyles.HexNumber, new CultureInfo( "en-US" ), out someLong );
```

will convert a hex string ( 0-9, A-F ) into it's corresponding value.

I want to convert a base 64 value ( 0-9 ( 10 ), a-z ( 26 ), A-Z ( 26 ) ) into it's corresponding integer value.

Is this possible, out of the box?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27493/Convert-an-integer-to-a-base-string-and-back-ag?

Comment: `10 + 26 + 26 = 62` You need two more chars :)

Comment: @L.B Crap; you're right. Well, you knew where I was going anyway...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how you can round-trip a `long` to/from Base-64:

```
long k = 123456789101112L;
string str = Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(k));
Console.WriteLine(str);
long x = BitConverter.ToInt64(Convert.FromBase64String(str), 0);
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", k, x, x==k);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/q8wkgt)

Answer (score 0):

Sure is,

There are a few different ways I have seen this done

Example 1

```
    var base64 = "ValueToBeConverted"; 
    var data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```

Example 2

```
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ValueToBeConverted"); 
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes); 
    Console.WriteLine(base64);
```

Example 3

```
    var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data); 
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Let me know if any of those work for you.

Comment: My mistake I misread. This is for base64 to string which a simple Convert.Int64() can go around